# PDO SQL Placeholder issue

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Can anyone figure out why this code isnt printing the value to the page?

```
$query_params = array(
            ':test1' => 'test1',
            ':test2' => 'test2'
);

// Count the number of records matching the first quota

$quota1Count = "SELECT COUNT(*)
               FROM :test1
               WHERE :test2 = 1";

try { 

        $stmt = $db->prepare($quota1Count); 
        $stmt->execute($query_params); 

    } 

catch(PDOException $ex) { 

        die("Failed to run query"); 
    } 

$quota1 = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

Printing to the page

```
Quota 1: <?= $quota1; ?>
```

When I dont use the PDO placeholders the code runs fine and returns the correct value:

```
$quota1Count = "SELECT COUNT(*)
               FROM test1
               WHERE test2 = 1";
```

Comment: simple: you can't bind tables and columns

Comment: why are you using :table1 instead of table1 in ur PDO query.?

Comment: @Fred-ii- is right you can bind only value not table or columns.thanks.

Comment: @Fred-ii- can you suggest another way to do this then? I would like to be able to define the table/column outside of the statement

Comment: use a whitelist method.

Comment: or pre-define variables. Plus, I've no idea why this question received a vote to reopen.